# How to call Stored Procedure from within a TVF?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, powerbi

I'd like to utilise an already written stored procedure having parameters and temp tables for a report with Power BI (DirectQuery).

I've tried to do so via table-valued function as shown below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [rpt].[ufnPBI0002_KPI]
    (@YearMonth nvarchar(20), -- = '2017-12'
     @Products  nvarchar(50), -- = '2,7,8'
     @Regions   nvarchar(50) -- = '1'
    )

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Return type
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

RETURNS TABLE

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Begin
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

AS

BEGIN

    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Declare return table
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    DECLARE @Result AS TABLE
        (
             SalesRegionId                          INT
            ,TotalCAcount                           INT
            ,EffectiveCAcount                       INT
            ,NewCA                                  INT
            ,Plan_Total_CA_count                    INT
            ,Plan_eCA_Count_All                     INT
            ,Plan_CA_Intake                         INT
            ,Plan_CA_PJ_count                       INT
            ,Plan_NV_Prod_PJ                        INT
            ,Plan_Avg_NV_All_per_eCA                INT
            ,BusinessLoanSpecialistCount            INT
            ,ProfiJuniors                           INT
            ,ActiveCAcount                          INT
            ,TerminatedCAcount                      INT
            ,NewNV                                  INT
            ,NewNVPJ                                INT
            ,AvgNVeCA                               INT
            ,AvgNVProfiJuniors                      INT
        )

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Handle stored procedure result
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    INSERT INTO @Result

        EXEC [rpt].[MR0002_KPI] @YearMonth, @Products, @Regions

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Return the result
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SELECT * FROM @Result

    RETURN;

-----------------------------------------------------------------------
-- END
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

END
```

Which returns

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 31, Procedure ufnPBI0002_KPI, Line 68 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near 'BEGIN'

I think it would not be possible to call a stored procedure from a TFV, but would really appreciate any hints, how to utilise parametric stored procedure with PBI.

Answer (score 1):

You can [not call stored procedures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine) from within a Function

**User-defined functions cannot call a stored procedure, but can call an extended stored procedure.**

Change the function to a stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to SSRS data sources, you do not have to use a function in your case, bit can just directly use a stored procedure:

```
 EXEC [rpt].[MR0002_KPI] @YearMonth, @Products, @Regions
```

Just refresh a dataset, it should be able to detect available columns returned by SP.

Moreover, your initial approach would result (if TVM allows SP) to unnecessary inserts to @Result table variable, so it could cause extra load on TEMPDB